# Data does not pause to API using curl

Tags: php, api, curl

The email does not pause to API

```
 <?php 
   function post_to_url($url, $data) {
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       $result = curl_exec ($ch);
       echo $result;
       curl_close ($ch);
   }
   $data = array( "email1" => "myemail@yahoo.com" );

   post_to_url("http://api.payquicker.com/api/IsActiveAccount?email=", $data);

 ?>
```

`echo $result;` should be----> `http://api.payquicker.com/api/IsActiveAccount?email=myemail@yahoo.com`

but im only getting `http://api.payquicker.com/api/IsActiveAccount?email=`

Comment: That's exactly your `$url`. `http_build_quary($data)` would look like `email1=myemail%40yahoo.com` -- you don't expect it to be magically "merge" with your `?email=` URL, do you?

Comment: @Passerby I should be getting a true value if a valid and registered email, what im getting is valid or not registered or not im getting false value from API return in xml format

Comment: What exactly do you want to post? What exactly do you want to get, and what were you getting instead? You may want to update more info into your question.

Comment: @Passerby when you open this URL http://api.payquicker.com/api/IsActiveAccount?email=myemail@yahoo.com and myemail@yahoo.com is a valid email and registered to payquicker an xml : <result>true</result>

Comment: what i wanted to post is email to verify if this email is registered. if not registered i will send to API email invitation to register this user

Comment: You can update your own question. And, `isActiveAccount?email=myemail%40yahoo.com` is not POST, it's GET. And even if the server accepts both method, your code is actually sending `email1=myemail%40yahoo.com` to `isActiveAccount?email=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 echo "<p><strong>SEND INVITATION</strong></p></BR>";
 $dataw = array(
            "authorizedKey" => "xxx-xxxx-xxx",
            "senderEmail" => "senderemail@yahoo.com",
            "recipientEmail" => "myemail@yahoo.com"
          );
$url_send ="https://api.payquicker.com/api/SendInvitation?authorizedKey=xxx-xxxx-xxx";
$str_data = json_encode($dataw);
function send_invitation($url, $post_data){
  $url_send =$url;
  $ch = curl_init($url_send);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,  false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,   "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,      $post_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',     
 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post_data))
 );
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
  //$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $result; 
  }
 echo "RESULT :" . send_invitation($url_send, $str_data);
```